# A criterion for metrizable topological spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space. True or false?

$X$ is metrizable if and only if it contains  a sequence of metrizable spaces $\{X_n\}$ with $X=\bigcup X_n$!

Comment: Please explain, what does it mean a sequence of spaces?

Comment: The line with double origin is a union of two metrizable spaces, but is not metrizable itself, as it is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @ Evgeny Kuznetsov I mean $X_n$ is just contained in $X$ for every $n$.

Comment: @ Corbennick  Nice example.

Comment: @Corbennick  Actually I faced a particular type of topological spaces and  would like to know whether they are well-known or not:  Let $X$ be a topological space. Let us say $X$ has property *P* if there  exists a metric $d$ on $X$ and a sequence of spaces $X_n\subseteq X$ such that all $X_n$ are $d$-metrizable and $X=\bigcup X_n$.

Comment: Isn't every countable $\text{T}_1$-space the union of a sequence of metrizable spaces?

Comment: @bof Yes, which means the answer to OP's question is false even if we restrict to increasing chains of metrizable subspaces (e.g., the integers with the cofinite topology).

Comment: Also, inductive limits of metric spaces in general are not metrizable. A typical obstruction is given by Baire theorem.